# rails 4 - require class in initializer or module that uses it - best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a fairly new RoR dev and ran into a question about best practices for `require` ing files from `lib` in Rails 4.

**Background:**

As it stands, files in my app's `lib` don't get autoloaded. I want to require a helper class called `rate_limiter` that lives in a subdirectory of `lib`. I've also created a `throttle` module that handles routes related to rate limiting, and uses this `rate_limiter` class.

The `throttle` module is already required at the top of my application controller.

**Question**: to make sure `rate_limiter` gets loaded at start of app, what's better:

1) include an initializer rate_limiter.rb that simply says `require rate_limiter` to load class.

2) add `require rate_limiter` to the top of a different module `throttle`, which uses `rate_limiter` and which already gets required at the top of application controller.

Wondering about best practices for clarity and maintainability going forward.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this would be a more Rails way to include desired files and folders.

```
# config/application.rb
module YourAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib')]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and apologies for my slow reply. I'll use this approach in the future. Ultimately for my original issue, we realized that not all files in `lib` should get autoloaded (some were old classes or rake tasks) and some errors were thrown, so I ended up requiring the particular file from lib at the top of the controller that used it (`require 'rate-limiter'`). Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You probably could try the following scheme:

```
# config/application.rb:

# To make sure that your module namespace will be initialized without name collisions with files in your app directories
# require only root file and autoload other relative files in root file using features of ActiveSupport::Autoload
require_relative '../lib/my_module/my_module'

module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Do not include all files in your lib. Require explicitly
    # .
    # ..
    # - lib/my_module/my_module.rb - root file
    # - lib/my_module/my_module - directory
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'my_module')]
  end
end
```

Then in you module you can specify explicitly which files required and when

```
# lib/my_module/my_module.rb 
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Autoload

  autoload :Configuration
  autoload :SomeClass # at lib/my_module/my_module/some_class.rb
  autoload :AnotherClass

  eager_autoload do
    autoload :Errors # at lib/my_module/my_module/errors.rb
    autoload :BillError, 'my_module/errors'
  end
end
```

It is worth to read an official [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) to understand generic process of Rails constant lookup

Answer (score 0):

To me, since this is going into your application controller which every request gets funneled through, I'd suggest adding this to your autoload paths.

In `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/mymodule)
```